# Python Selenium: 2 buttons with same class?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on button with class `btn3`, but there is another button on same page with same class.

Button I want to click:

```
<div class="btn3">Follow</div>
```

Button I DON'T want to click:

```
<div class="btn3">Add Site/Page</div>
```

My code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn3').click()
```

Comment: Don't you have a way to indicate the position of it in the file? Meaning 1st, 2nd... http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html

Comment: Is there more to the html than the div tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this -

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn3')[0].click()
```

Or,

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Follow').click()
```

Comment: Does `find_element_by_link_text` works for buttons? I'd use xpath, personally.

Comment: Thanks so much. Why so many downvotes tho? :(

Thought stacksoverflow was made for people to ask questions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these buttons are inside some other elements and not attached directly to body, you can change your code to

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.first_div .btn3').click()`

(change class name accordingly)